# PHP Generate random number without repetition without loop for mt_rand and without using range() and shuffle()

Tags: php, random

I am looking for a way to generate a specific quantity of unique random numbers (say 10,000), within a specific range of numbers like (000000000,999999999).

I'd like to do this without repeatedly using `rand()` or `mt_rand()` under a `for` loop as this would be computationally inefficient.

Are there any PHP libraries, or solutions which meets these requirements?

Comment: Questions asking for links to software libraries are off-topic, I'm afraid. But are you sure `mt_rand()` isn't fast enough? It should be able to generate millions of numbers per second, so ten thousand would take very little time at all.

Comment: Have you tried with uniqid ? echo hexdec(uniqid());

Comment: @Bikesh That's not *random*.

Comment: There aren't that many approaches… Either you use a random number large enough from a generator of sufficient quality so that it's *statistically unlikely enough* that you'll get a duplicate value, or you explicitly deduplicate your values, or you generate all possible values and do random picks.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use a [Format Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption), with the output limited to the range 0 to 999999999.  If you encrypt the numbers 0 to 9,999 you will get 10,000 unique outputs in the required range.  With an encryption, unique inputs guarantee unique outputs as long as you don't change the key.

Comment: You should probably elaborate a bit more…

Comment: I do not know enough PHP to give much elaboration.  All I could do it to give advice on the specifics of the cryptography end.  I do not know the PHP crypto libraries or how easy it is to write a 30-bit Feistel cipher in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a class that keeps state of generation:

```
class Randomizer {
  private $min;
  private $max;
  private $maxGeneration; 

  public function __construct($min = 0, $max = 100) {
    if ($min >= $max) {
      throw new Exception('Minimal value is more than or equal to Max value');
    }

    if ($max - $min < 3) {
      throw new Exception('Nothing to randomize');
    } 

    $this->min = $min;
    $this->max = $max;
    $this->maxGeneration = $max - $min - 1;
  }

  public function pick($quantity = 1) {
    $count = 0;
    $generated = [];
    while($count < $quantity) {
      $num = $this->generate();

      if (sizeof($generated) === $this->maxGeneration) {
        break;
      }

      if (!in_array($num, $generated)) {
        $generated[] = $num;
        $count++;
      }
    }
    return ($quantity === 1) ? $generated[0] : $generated;
  }

  public function generate() {
    return mt_rand($this->min, $this->max);
  }
}
```

2) Use it:

```
$randomizer = new Randomizer(0, 999999999);
$number = $randomizer->pick(); // returns 1 number
$numbers = $randomizer->pick(100); // returns array(A, B, C...) of numbers
```

Comment: That hardly qualifies as "without loop".

Comment: @deceze I've seen it and modified it to return a number or array of numbers

Comment: Still seeing a loop there…

Comment: His question specifies "* a specific quantity*" ... how did you get to the calculation `(($max - $min) / 2)` for `$this->maxGeneration`?

Comment: @billynoad removed that and made it to be able to specify quantity :)

Comment: @deceze I think he tries to avoid getting same numbers inside while loop and looks for more simple method. I don't know such method that can return array of unique (not repeating) numbers.